# How to alter a table and add in a date column which doesn't allow dates before a certain date in sql?

Tags: sql, date, alter, pgadmin-4

I need an sql query to alter a table to add in a date column, which is the part I know how to do. What I don't know how to do is specify that the dates in the column need to be after a certain date.

**My latest attempt:**

```
ALTER TABLE <table name>
ADD constraint <constraint name>
CHECK (<column name>(date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') >= '2000-01-01');
```

I'm using pgadmin4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
ALTER TABLE t ADD constraint chk_t_col CHECK (col >= '2000-01-01');
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!